# Are DAOs supposed to return instances or just their data?

Tags: design-patterns

Suppose I have a [DAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) which touches the DB.

Should the DAO return only data and then it's up to me to do the instantiation or is the DAO supposed to also do the instantiation and return me the instance - and why should I choose one method over another?

```js
// Example with instantiation
studentDAO = {
  getById: function() {
    const data = db.query('SELECT FROM `students`...');

    return new Student(data);
  }
}

// Example without instantiation (just returns the data)
studentDAO = {
  getById: function() {
    const data = db.query('SELECT FROM `students`...');

    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should return the instance, because the purpose of the dao is to hide the database implementation from the rest of the code and your data object is specific to your db.

In fact you should even avoid passing data into a constructor as in your example.

eg.

```
studentDAO = 
{
    getById: function() 
    { 
        const data = db.query('SELECT FROM `students`...');

        var s = new Student();
        s.Id = data[0]: 
        //that data can be accessed like this and that element 0 
        //contains the student Id is information specific to the 
        //database and the responsibility of the DAO class NOT the 
        //Student class

        return s;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks - Why should I avoid passing data to the constructor?

Comment: because then your constructor, which is not part of the dao needs to know about the data type and structure. this should be kept inside the dao

Comment: Not *entirely* sure what you mean - Care to share a small example or explain a bit more? I understand that the constructor shouldn't know about the data structure that comes from the DB but what's an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: done, excuse smart phone editor

Comment: Avoiding proper constructors is not a best practice! In this example, a `new Student(data[0])` would be no more coupled than `var s = new Student(); s.Id = data[0]`, but the latter is more likely to contain bugs, e.g. if new fields are added to the Student that must also be initialized. But except for this very unusual design, the main point of the answer is spot on: to be a proper abstraction, the DAL has to operate on domain objects like Student.

Comment: yes I just wanted to take what would presumably be the code inside the constructor and transplant it to the DAO to demonstrate the point.

Comment: `I understand that the constructor shouldn't know about the data structure that comes from the DB but what's an alternative way of doing this?` with mappers. One more "abstraction" that do care of transforming the db resultset into student instances :-).

Comment: or you just do it like i suggest, or pass the individual variables into a full constructor as @amon suggests. you dont need a mapper

Comment: Exactly. Depends on how many abstractions do you really need. As usual KISS. If you don't see the point to the mappers, do what Ewan or amon suggest

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides - most database libraries aren't gonna return, say, some string when you call `db.query`. It's probably gonna be some kind of cursor pointing at rows. You don't want to pass those to `Student`'s constructor, but rather extract the meaningful data from there (eg, the student's name, ID, etc. You'd also perhaps want to do error checking there like seeing if the expecting number of rows was obtained. It's totally fine to pass data into the constructor, but you'd probably want it to be eg, a string name, an int ID, etc as opposed to a DB cursor (or similar).

Answer (score 1):

- If by data you mean a resultset or a cursor, them NO, a DAO should not return that.
- If by data you mean a string of comma-separated values, a JSON string or a business object, the it is OK. In the cases of reports, a string of comma or TAB-separated values seems like a very good option.

Comment: Returning something like a JSON object is totally fine. But if there exists some business logic object like `Student`, you should return that as opposed to simply the exact data that would normally go into a `Student`.